# Groupby - taking last element - how do I keep nan's?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df and I want to grab the most recent row below by CUSIP.

```
In [374]: df.head()
Out[374]: 
              CUSIP        COLA         COLB       COLC  
date                                                          
1992-05-08    AAA          238         4256      3.523346   
1992-07-13    AAA          NaN         4677      3.485577   
1992-12-12    BBB          221         5150      3.24
1995-12-12    BBB          254         5150      3.25
1997-12-12    BBB          245         Nan       3.25
1998-12-12    CCC          234         5140      3.24145
1999-12-12    CCC          223         5120      3.65145
```

I am using:

```
df = df.reset_index().groupby('CUSIP').last().reset_index.set_index('date')
```

I want this:

```
              CUSIP        COLA         COLB       COLC  
date           
1992-07-13    AAA          NaN         4677      3.485577      
1997-12-12    BBB          245         Nan       3.25
1999-12-12    CCC          223         5120      3.65145
```

Instead I am getting:

```
              CUSIP        COLA         COLB       COLC  
date           
1992-07-13    AAA          238         4677      3.485577      
1997-12-12    BBB          245         5150       3.25
1999-12-12    CCC          223         5120      3.65145
```

How do I get last() to take the last row of the groupby including the NaN's?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this directly with an apply instead of last (and get the -1th row of each group):

```
In [11]: df.reset_index().groupby('CUSIP').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).reset_index(drop=True).set_index('date')
Out[11]: 
           CUSIP  COLA  COLB      COLC
date                                  
1992-07-13   AAA   NaN  4677  3.485577
1997-12-12   BBB   245   NaN  3.250000
1999-12-12   CCC   223  5120  3.651450

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

In 0.13 (rc out now), a faster and more direct way will be to use [cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items):

```
In [12]: df[df.groupby('CUSIP').cumcount(ascending=False) == 0]
Out[12]: 
           CUSIP  COLA  COLB      COLC
date                                  
1992-07-13   AAA   NaN  4677  3.485577
1997-12-12   BBB   245   NaN  3.250000
1999-12-12   CCC   223  5120  3.651450

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: To confirm, the cumcount approach would require resetting the index in a line before, correct?

Also, does it need to be pd.cumcount?

Comment: @user1911092 in 0.13 there is a cumcount groupby method, the code above is copy and pasted. (So no, you don't need to reset the index :) )

Comment: @DanAllan I'm kindof shocked that last does this (I knew it did for Series groupby...) it's annoying for refactoring with cumcount! Perhaps there's scope for doing something clever... These functions are **slow** atm.